# Unidentified network with VIRTIO NIC Drivers after system reboot

Tags: networking, redhat, kvm-virtualization, nic, virtio

I have KVM with VIRTIO network interface. It runs under Windows Server 2012 R2 so I installed RedHat network virtio drivers. It runs properly but after system reboot internet connection is lost. Network card has yellow sign and it described as Unidentified Network. When I manually disable and enable network adapter it works again. Cant understand why this happen and what I can do to fix it. Of course I can make a script to be executed at startup that disable and enable interface, but I need more proper solution.

Found similar problem [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/229423) with solution, but cant view it :'D

Comment: Here's that solution: 1. Power-OFF the windows VM - IF its using a e1000 card
2. Assign a "Red Hat Virtio" card to this VM.
3. Power-ON the VM.
4. After power-ON, Navigate to Device manager in windows.
5. Double click on the virtio network card being used inside the VM
6. Navigate to Advanced tab
7. Change Init.UsePublishEvents to "Disabled"
8. Click OK.
9. Close the Device manager.
10. Reboot the VM

Comment: I'm glad.  Feel free to format this as an answer and mark it answered (you did do all the work)